# Apache Rewrite Rule for https subdomain redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

I have a following Apache Configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On

            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
            RewriteRule ^/(.*)         https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

I does redirect for the following URLs:

```
http://subdomain.example.com -> https://www.example.com
http://example.com -> https://www.example.com
https://example.com -> https://www.example.com
```

However, it does not work for the following URL:

```
https://subdomain.example.com -> https://subdomain.example.com (instead of https://www.example.com)
```

Due to this, the user which enters the last URL receives a prompt that certificate is incorrect (understandable — domains don't match). Is there a way to correct this, so that all redirects go to `https://www.example.com` ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create virtual host for subdomain.example.com and implement rewrite rule there which will redirect https://subdomain.example.com to https://www.example.com

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName subdomain.example.com
   RewriteEngine On
      RedirectPermanent / https://www.example.com/
     </VirtualHost>
```